# What is maximum value of constant timer in jmeter? My test stops after 4 mins

Tags: jmeter

My test is configured like below.

Thread group is configured to run for 9600s which is 160 mins that is 2 hours 50 mins.

within that I have placed constant timer as 1800000(ms) as that parameter is to be provided in ms. when I start the test, it stops within 4 mins and I can see in log that:
Stop test detected by thread:...

Is there any limit for constant timer, I.E. what could be the reason my test is stopping after 4 mins ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such limitation on Constant Timer. The error could be because of some other reason.

Share the error message and other configuration details in Thread Group. Also share View Results Tree screen shot after running the test

**Note:** Test will stop automatically if Jmeter completes with script execution irrespective of the time mentioned in scheduler. so, you should provide enough loop count (or mark forever), so that test would run till the scheduled time completes.